# Android bitmap allocating 16 BYTES per pixel

Tags: android, graphics

I've got a program which is loading resources from the resource file (by setting android:src="@drawable/image" in the layout file.

The image is 800 x 1280 pixels. When the program runs it allocates 16,384,000 bytes on the heap which is 16 BYTES per pixel.

I assumed that it should default to RGB8888 which only uses 4 bytes per pixel. Anyone know how I can change this to use less memory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your images could be stored in an inappropiate folder. If you have high resolution images in a low resolution folder, let's say, the images are 800 x 1280 and you're storing it in drawable or drawable-hdpi, Android will scale them up to match xhdpi (although they are already in xhdpi, so to say). The scaled image occupies more memory.

Solution, put them in drawable-xhdpi.

Comment: Scaling ldpi (120 dpi) up to xhdpi (320dpi) should be no more than a factor of 2 2/3 but 16 byte per pixel are at least factor 4. I'm also not sure if Android actually scales images up. Small images can still be drawn bigger than they are.

Comment: Here are some maths. Let's take 320 x 480 px as example for mdpi resolution and 800 x 1280 px for xhdpi: 320 x 480: 153600 * 4 = 614400 ----

800 x 1280: 1024000 * 4 = 4096000----

Comment: And 4096000 bytes / 614400 bytes = 6.66 factor

Comment: Oops, you are right, your math is slightly off though. If 320 x 480 is ldpi (=120dpi) then the xhdpi (320dpi) is 853px x 1280px which means it's 153600 px vs 1091840 px = factor 7.1 which happens to be (2 2/3)^2 - that means that factor 4 is an increase of 2x in terms of dpi which would fit perfectly for mdpi - xhdpi.

Comment: Android does indeed scale bitmaps if the app does not make a version of that asset available for the device's native density. A 1280x800 bitmap placed in a drawable-mdpi/ folder will be scaled to 2560x1600 (4x pixel count) on an xhdpi device. Images placed in drawable/ are treated as mdpi. drawable-nodpi/ is provided for images that you do not want scaled for density. (Reference: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html )

Answer (score 0):

you can import them using BitmapFactory, Options, and inSampleSize to reduce the memory footprint.

Also, that seems like a very high res image to display on a mobile screen so you could also reduce the size?

Comment: xhdpi handset screens can easily reach 720x1280 or higher these days, and 1280x800 is a standard resolution for mdpi 10" tablets. The Nexus 10's screen is 2560x1600; a 1280x800 bitmap would only cover a quarter of the screen area on that device. Depending on where and how they're being used, bitmaps of this size are entirely valid.

Comment: that's totally right - been thinking about 4.7' phones and the 720x1280 as a max. Clearly I need to remember tablets!

Comment: @MrFox yes please :) Too many apps out there that have issues with tables. And it's not just creepy layout. All the apps that require typical phone features like a back-facing camera don't run on them if they have just a front-facing camera for example. Apps that force portait mode are annoying to use since you have to turn that huge tablet all the time. Just to name those that are quite commonly annoying me.

Answer (score 0):

Check the documentation about bytes per pixel: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.Config.html

You can try using Color.RGB_565, but the image may lose quality.